# Trying to insert an array into another with splice and spread, returning empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use the splice method to add the values from the first array into the second array in the index location provided by the third parameter. I was confident that my solution would work, even verified that my understanding of slice was correct. However, when I log this in console it returns as an empty array.

I feel like I am really close, but something is missing.

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
//copies made as to not disrupt referece.
let array1 = arr1.slice(0, arr1.length);
let array2 = arr2.slice(0, arr2.length);
let mutatedArray = array2.splice(n,0,...array1);

return mutatedArray;}
```

frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 1) should return [4, 1, 2, 3, 5].

Also, is this a good usage of creating copies of the arrays in the function? I'm learning about referencing non-primitives and if I'm not mistaken creating the copies in the scope of the function protects the original reference from being modified. It's not pointless in this context is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the return value for `splice` is not the array that got mutated, but the [*removed elements*, in an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value):

> Return value: An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

You aren't removing any elements with `splice`, so the result is an empty array. Don't assign the result of `splice` to a variable, and `return array2` instead:

```js
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  //copies made as to not disrupt referece.
  let array1 = arr1.slice(0, arr1.length);
  let array2 = arr2.slice(0, arr2.length);
  array2.splice(n, 0, ...array1);
  return array2;
}
console.log(frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 1))
```

Also note that you can use `slice()` without any arguments to create a shallow copy of an array, no need for `(0, arr.length)`:

```js
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  //copies made as to not disrupt referece.
  let array1 = arr1.slice();
  let array2 = arr2.slice();
  array2.splice(n, 0, ...array1);
  return array2;
}
console.log(frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 1))
```

Another option is to immediately return an array into which you spread `sliced` sections of the original arrays, which might be clearer than using `splice`:

```js
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  return [
    ...arr2.slice(0, n),
    ...arr1,
    ...arr2.slice(n)
  ];
}
console.log(frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the cleaner slice version and the alternate solution, it's pretty clever!